# Best way to push change data from sql server to windows/web application

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have win apps which will load all data initially from and display through grid but from then next when any data will change in db or any data will be inserted newly in db then only change or newly inserted data need to be pushed from d site to my win apps. now only sql dependency class is coming to my mind but there is a problem regarding sql dependency class that it notify client but do not say which data is updated or inserted.

so i am looking for best guidance and easy way to achieve my task. what will be the best way to push data from sql server to win or web client.

Answer (score 0):

Will change tracking work for you? [SQL Server Change Tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx)

Comment: SQL Server Change Tracking can push data from db to win apps or not? if we can only detect change that is not sufficient for my scenario. i am looking for easy way to push data from db side to win apps.

Comment: I never used it myself. If you read the article it looks like when you are notified of the change you then need to query for the changed information yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [SQLDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  In a nutshell: you set up a query, and get notified whenever the results of that query change.

I believe this just notifies you of the change--you then need to query the data to get the actual differences.

Comment: SQLDependency will not work for me because it never notify which data update....i want a technique which notify me about which records gets updated. if u know anything similar sort of anything then let me know. thanks